# How do I select this svg object using css selector?

Tags: python, selenium, svg, css-selectors

I have an svg object that I am unable to find by the object name

[image]

code used:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ql-editor-ql-blank.p"))).send_keys("hello world")
```

i tried

```
"div[class='ql-editor-ql-blank'].p"

"ql-editor.p"

"div[class='ql-editor'].p"

"div[class='ql-editor-ql-blank'].p"
```

They all fail with at timeout exception.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

How do I access this nested svg object?

I tried the other non standard key:values within the div tag with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in the screenshot, the correct css selector should be

```
".ql-editor p"
```

since `ql-editor` is a class and `p` is an element.